# How to send order id into paypal from ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, paypal, payment-gateway

I have to send the orderid to paypal gateway.i am using the paypal(1.0.5)

I tried like this

```
 payment.shortDescription = stringOrderId;
```

But the orderid is not displayed in my palpal account.How to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you tell what your Order Id string is ? Also do a NSLog for the stringOrderId & check the value. Let me know so that I can rectify your problem.

Comment: I am getting the integer value as orderid Ex:761234

Comment: Use proper format specifier like %d instead of %@

Comment: even i write payment.shortDescription = @"Hi"; also it is not showing the string in paypal

Comment: Please get the latest version & refer the code link pointed in my updated answer.

Comment: @Madhu Have you worked on paypal MPL?

Comment: @Pradhyuman Chavda Yes,But for credit card option, i moved from MPL to latest paypal library(1.4.3)

Comment: @Madhu ok... sry for disturb you.

Comment: Nop.If u have any Queries u can ask.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that whatever string you pass to the "shortDescription" it should not exceed 20 characters. If that exceeds, it will be truncated. Refer [here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/blob/master/PayPalMobile/PayPalPayment.h#L59)

Also, plz check the size width of component that you might be using to display the shortDescription, in case.

You should also do a proper formatting while converting from Integer to String. Please use %d or higher order formatter specifier, as referred [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html) in apple documentation.

Please upgrade to the latest version of [PayPal iOS SDK 1.4.3](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK) & do check the code in the mentioned in this file [ZZMainViewController.m](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/blob/3592099e9e768362f444417ac4866d94b4fb714c/SampleApp/PayPal-iOS-SDK-Sample-App/ZZMainViewController.m#L84)

Comment: But my string length not exceed 6 to 7 characters.

Comment: even i write payment.shortDescription = @"Hi"; also it is not showing the string in paypal

Comment: Please get the latest version & refer the code link pointed in my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Dave from PayPal here.

Our [most recent FAQs](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/faq/#mobile-sdk-questions) now address your question. Unfortunately, the answer is:

**Is there a way to get the payment description string to show up in the transaction details on PayPal.com?**

*No, this is not supported functionality.*