# short description is not showing in PayPal Site

Tags: ios, iphone, paypal, payment-gateway

[image]When i make a transaction from my iOS App using PayPal(Version 1.4.3), i can't see the short description in the user PayPal Account in the website. Transaction is working fine. Below is my code

```
    PayPalPayment *payment = [[PayPalPayment alloc] init];
        payment.amount = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"0.5"]; //Amount is static for testing
        payment.currencyCode = @"USD";
        payment.shortDescription = @"Order";
 self.acceptCreditCards = YES;
        self.environment = PayPalEnvironmentProduction;
        [PayPalPaymentViewController setEnvironment:self.environment];

        PayPalPaymentViewController *paymentViewController = [[PayPalPaymentViewController alloc] initWithClientId:kPayPalClientId receiverEmail:kPayPalReceiverEmail payerId:nil payment:payment delegate:self];

        paymentViewController.title=@"Order";
        paymentViewController.hideCreditCardButton = !self.acceptCreditCards;

        [self presentViewController:paymentViewController animated:YES completion:nil];![enter image description here][2]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the similar question (on problem basis) to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20565779/how-to-send-order-id-into-paypal-from-ios/20566793?noredirect=1#comment30763662_20566793). But now it looks like, the short description is not meant to be shown on the "History Details". Kindly search the transaction history & then verify.

May be this appears in the statement issued by the bank issuing the "Financial Instrument" used to perform this transaction.

I have verified all my transaction detail in my account & I do not see any column or label for the Payment Description on my Transaction Detail Page.

Comment: What is my requirement to use that parameter is, when user is purchasing a product from my app using PayPal, then server will generate a unique id for that transaction, that uniqueid iam assigning to that shortDescription, so that user can use that uniqueid later to track the status of the purchase. That unique id we want to display in the transaction details in the User paypal page. Can we have any other parameter to use?

Comment: I understand your concern and I would suggest you to try looking for the actual API call which is used by this iOS wrapper classes. Currently the actual API is presented as a compiled library with this SDK. You can definitely raise concern & a ticket in GitHub seeking information about the display of "shortDescription" on transaction detail page.

Comment: Also try to see the adaptive payments api on PayPal developer site or try it on "www.X.com" ( it was a developer innovation forum, I am not sure if it's still up & running)

Comment: x.com isn't really supported anymore... PayPal is moving to developer.paypal.com instead.

Answer (score 0):

Dave from PayPal here.

Our [most recent FAQs](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/faq/#mobile-sdk-questions) now address your question. Unfortunately, the answer is:

**Is there a way to get the payment description string to show up in the transaction details on PayPal.com?**
*No, this is not supported functionality.*